# Position View at the bottom (Sticky Footer), React Native

Tags: react-native, flexbox, react-native-flexbox, flexboxgrid

I have this Component:

```
    render() {
    return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.body}>
                <View style={styles.LogoContainer}>
                    <Image resizeMode="contain" style={styles.logo} source={require('../../images/logo.png')}/>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.bottomContainer}>
                    <TextInput selectionColor="white" placeholderTextColor="white" placeholder="Email" style={styles.input} underlineColorAndroid='transparent'/>
                    <TextInput selectionColor="white" placeholderTextColor="white" secureTextEntry={true} placeholder="Password" style={styles.input} underlineColorAndroid='transparent'/>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}} style={styles.btn}>
                        <Text style={styles.btnTxt}>LOG IN</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.footer}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}}>
                    <Text style={[styles.footerTxt, {color: '#fff'}]}>Don’t have an account?</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    )
}
```

What I want is to position the latest view with `style={styles.footer}` (Sticky Footer). I tried to set `position: "absolute, bottom:0"`, but not working. Parent container (`ScrollView`) has `height:"100%"` and `position:"relative"`, if this matter for React Native.

Comment: What do you mean by "not to be fixed" ? Your question needs to further explanation.

Comment: Hi I mean not with `position:fixed` at the bottom. Not Sticky Footer.

Comment: Care to draw the layout you want? I still don't know what you want.

Comment: You need to provide your style as well. "Sticky footer" normally mean _"positioned at bottom of the viewport even with smaller content, but pushed down with bigger content"_, what does it mean to you?

Comment: I mean if you scroll the footer moves like every other element and if the sum of all content is less than  screen height, the footer to be at the bottom.

Comment: That is a "Sticky footer", which you say you don't want, so update your question and remove that, along with adding the styles.

Answer (score 0):

I found this way. First remove `<View style={styles.body}>` element and add `contentContainerStyle` to the `ScrollView` like this:

```
render() {
return (
        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.LogoContainer}>
                <Image resizeMode="contain" style={styles.logo} source={require('../../images/logo.png')}/>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.bottomContainer}>
                <TextInput selectionColor="white" placeholderTextColor="white" placeholder="Email" style={styles.input} underlineColorAndroid='transparent'/>
                <TextInput selectionColor="white" placeholderTextColor="white" secureTextEntry={true} placeholder="Password" style={styles.input} underlineColorAndroid='transparent'/>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}} style={styles.btn}>
                    <Text style={styles.btnTxt}>LOG IN</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.footer}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}}>
                    <Text style={[styles.footerTxt, {color: '#fff'}]}>Don’t have an account?</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
      )
}
```

Next add these styles to the `ScrollView`:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container:{
   flex: 1,
   justifyContent: 'space-between',
}, ....
```

and if needed can be added `height` to the `ScrollView > View`.